# jQuery submit only subpart of form (files-input)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have a Form with some fields:

```
<form action="xyz.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="firstname">
 ...
 <input type="file" name="logo">
 ...
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The image should be uploaded immediately to `img_upload.php`. In this file i need the `$_FILES` array.
My `img_upload.php` script uploads the image, do some things with the image (resize, ...) and give me the URL to the image. After this, the image should be displayed in the form.

Is there any chance to upload the image (send `$_FILES` array to another file) without submiting the whole form?

Comment: You can't upload files using Ajax. Use a plugin like http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="file" name="logo" onchange="uploadThisFile(this)" >

function uploadThisFile(file) {
    /* launch an ajax request to  img_upload.php and pass file details via POST */
}
```

Comment: Ok, i guess then you can use a hidden iframe to upload the file.